# Vuejs select option does not change value on post

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a basic select option I get the option data server side using php (php blade) like this:

```
            <select name="selectedLanguage"
                    v-model="selectedLanguage">
                @foreach($languages as $language)
                    <option value="{{ $language }}">{{ $language }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

I basically get a bunch on languages.

In my vue instance I try to post the selected data using axios like this:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#snippet-form',


    data: {
        selectedLanguage: ''
    },


    methods: {

        publish (e) {
            var self = this;
            axios.post('/foo',  {
                selectedLanguage: this.selectedLanguage
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
        },
},
```

});

But everytime the server returns me null, the value does not change if I change the selectedLanguage in my data object to English it returns english but not the selected language from my select option field. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the DOM, in order to check what the values of the `option` tags are ?